# F# FSI does not hit break inside inline function

Tags: debugging, f#, inline, f#-interactive

I have several generic inline functions, e.g.:

```
let inline getRatesImpl<'T when 'T : (member enantiomer : 'T) and 'T : equality> 
    (d : Dictionary<'T, (ReactionRate option * ReactionRate option)>) 
    (calculateRates : 'T -> RelatedReactions<'T>)
    (r : 'T) = 

    match d.TryGetValue r with 
    | true, rates -> 
        rates
    | false, _ -> 
        updateRelatedReactions d (calculateRates r) r
```

The functions are used like that:

```
type FoodCreationModel (p : FoodCreationParam) = 
    let rateDictionary = new Dictionary<FoodCreationReaction, (ReactionRate option * ReactionRate option)>()
    let calculateRates _ = getRates (Some p.foodCreationRate, Some 1.0) (None, None)

    member __.getRates r = 
        getRatesImpl rateDictionary calculateRates r

    member __.inputParams = p
```

When I put a break inside `getRatesImpl` it is not hit in FSI. Even if I put a break, for example, on `getRates` (on line `getRatesImpl rateDictionary calculateRates r`) and then press F11, then FSI does not get inside `inline getRatesImpl`. However, it does work and I can check that by looking at how the dictionary changes before and after the call.

Some of these inline functions are quite complicated and I really need to debug them once in a while.

The question is how?

Comment: I find debug break don't work with inline.Can you split the inline function in two parts. A part that is required to be inline and one part that is not inlined. The inline function extracts all informaiton that can only be collected in inline functions and call the non-inline part which contains the complex logic. That way you can debug the non-inlined logic. Other than I think you need to rely on `printfn`.

Comment: @ Justanothermetaprogrammer As unfortunate as it is, but inability of FSI to debug in inline functions qualifies as an answer. I'd be glad to mark it as an answer it you put it as an answer, not as a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code probably can be changed to avoid the need for complicated `inline`s.

One way to avoid using SRTP is passing the required functions as a parameter instead of a constraint:

```
let getRatesImpl
        (d : Dictionary<'T, (ReactionRate option * ReactionRate option)>) 
        (getEnantiomer: 'T -> 'T)
        (calculateRates : 'T -> RelatedReactions<'T>)
        (r : 'T) = 

    match d.TryGetValue r with 
    | true, rates -> 
        rates
    | false, _ -> 
        updateRelatedReactions d getEnantiomer (calculateRates r) r
```

now `getRatesImpl` does not need to be inlined.

If more than one function is needed then a record of functions can be passed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 1. The whole system is built on DU / record trees. The proposed `IEnantiomer` interface is a C# way of doing things. Yes, it works but the cost is too high: to start from, classes will be used instead of DU / records  => all comparisons will have to be overloaded by hands before the objects can be easily used in various dictionaries. 2. The question was not about better implementation of dictionary but, rather about how to debug F# inline functions and I chose the simplest of the functions to illustrate the issue. If you have the answer on the question, I'd appreciate.

Comment: 2.- I included the memoization library because it seemed like you were doing it in a rather complicated way that forced you to use SRTPs which in turn forced you to use inlines. Of course the answer to the debug question is that you cannot debug inlines because they are not one function but many, one for each call. If you want to add breakpoints stay away from SRTPs and inlined functions.

Comment: 1.- I proposed interfaces because your example is using classes, which as you say 'is a C# thing'. By the way using Interfaces does not force you to change DUs or records to classes. They, DUs and records, can perfectly implement interfaces. I changed my answer to show this.

Comment: Having said that, I no longer recommend using interfaces since you do not want to use OOP, which I applaud. You probably do not need SRTPs but a simple `getEnantiomer` function  would do. Just post your Enantiomer functions and maybe we can figure out how to reorganize them so you can debug them easily without inlining.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I've yet to find the need of using interfaces in pure F# code. SRTPs do that without all the bloat. I already have function `let inline getEnantiomer i = ((^T) : (member enantiomer : 'T) (i))`, which is used by some of the generic functions, which eventually get used by `getRatesImpl`, which forces it to have generic constraint `member enantiomer`. The problem is that inline functions cannot be debugged :( This seems to be a drawback of current implementation.

Comment: SRTPs are better avoided, they can be useful in limited cases, but most of the time there is a better option. Probably for your case, what you need is a `getEnantiomer` 
(a non SRTP one) function that uses `match` across the DU to call the specific `enantiomer` members/functions.

Comment: That would require elevating all `'T`s into some DU, let's call it `MasterDu`. Sure, this can be done. However, the things like `(calculateRates : 'T -> RelatedReactions<'T>)` would become `(calculateRates : MasterDu -> RelatedReactions<MasterDu>)` thus losing the specifics that they operate only on some concrete type `'T`.  I have a feeling that that would do more harm than good. And, by the way, why SRTPs should be avoided? :)

Comment: When SRTP are overused (and a good measure of this is: how many functions and how deep they need to be inlined) your code becomes harder to maintain and debug: error messages become cryptic, function signatures are either empty or too convoluted, debugging capabilities disapear as you cannot: step into the functions, see intermediate values, add breakpoints. SRTPs are good for building DSL and to be used in expressions with operators, but if they become too nested then the code becomes harder to read an reason.

Comment: Instead of `calculateRates : MasterDu -> RelatedReactions<MasterDu>` it would probably be: `calculateRates : MasterDu -> RelatedReactions` without the generic result which makes the whole solution simpler in my opinion. Again, I do not really know or understand your problem Domain and how your types interact but I am throwing an educated guess here.

Comment: You are correct about RelatedReactions, The issue is that elevating `'T` (which should've been called `'R` there) would make the following generic type lose type constraint `('R * 'C) -> 'RC`:


`type CatRatesInfo<'R, 'C, 'RC when 'C : (member enantiomer : 'C) and 'C : equality> = 
        {
            reaction : 'R
            catalyst : 'C
            catReactionCreator : ('R * 'C) -> 'RC
            getBaseRates : 'R -> (ReactionRate option * ReactionRate option)
            eeParams : CatRatesEeParams
        }`


This type forces `enantiomer` constraint and SRTPs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185716/discussion-between-amieres-and-konstantin-konstantinov).